# Mount worked in 23.04, fails in 23.10

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

Did a complete wipe and fresh install going from 23.04 to 23.10.1  This shell scripted worked in 23.04

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=larry,pass=xxx,uid=1000,gid=1000 //10.0.0.21/Movies /smb/Helios4/Movies
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=larry,pass=xxx,uid=1000,gid=1000 //10.0.0.21/TV     /smb/Helios4/TV
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=larry,pass=xxx,uid=1000,gid=1000 //10.0.0.21/Misc   /smb/Helios4/Misc
```

Here's what I've looked at:

```
larry@minis-l: ls -ld /smb
drwxr-xr-x 5 larry larry 4096 Nov 11 22:33 /smb
larry@minis-l: ls -l /smb
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 5 larry larry 4096 Nov 11 22:34 fs1
drwxrwxr-x 6 larry larry 4096 Nov 11 22:35 Helios4
drwxrwxr-x 4 larry larry 4096 Nov 11 22:34 Minis
larry@minis-l: ls -l /smb/Helios4
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry 4096 Nov 11 22:33 Misc
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry    0 Aug  4 08:48 Movies
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry    0 Mar 12  2023 Other
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry    0 Aug 25 11:23 TV
larry@minis-l: sudo mount -t cifs -o user=larry,pass=maddog,uid=1000,gid=1000 //10.0.0.21/Misc   /smb/Helios4/Misc
mount: /smb/Helios4/Misc: cannot mount //10.0.0.21/Misc read-only.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
larry@minis-l: dmesg
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

All the directories up to and including the mount point look the same, why would just one fail?

I have a similar shell script to mount the fs1 and minis disks, they all fail with the same can not mount read only.  I do note that if I go into the file manager (nautilus?) and goto Other Locations, Networks, and select the drive there it mounts fine.  What does the file manager do differently?

EDIT: This is the output from "sudo dmesg"

```
[50664.125719] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
[50664.125827] CIFS: Attempting to mount //10.0.0.21/Misc
[50666.173499] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

journalctl -f had the same message, mount failed w/return code -13

If I read the man page for mount, return code 13 would be 8, 4, and 1 Where 8=user interrupt, 4= internal mount bug, and 1 incorrect invocation or permissions.  ???

Comment: You also can try to look into journal with `journalctl -f` and from an other terminal you can try to mount your share, the journal should you show whats wrong.

Comment: What happens when you add `vers=1` , `vers=2`, or `vers=3` to your mount options?  `-13` return code typically means auth failure, but also can mean that you have incorrect Samba / SMB version specified, etc.

Comment: @ThomasWard vers=3 has the same error mesg, vers=2 and vers=1 message says that I might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.  Two things - this is a brand new load of 23.10, so I could be missing something, but why would the other two mounts from the same source system work, but not the third?

Comment: @LarryM That I can't answer (check the logs on where your shares are?) unfortunately.  It also sounds like you might be missing Samba cli.ent, etc. to make things work, but it ALSO might be a case that your system is "too new" for your CIFS shares.  If your CIFS server only supports SMB v1 or v2 it might be too new and the older versions blocked, because v1 and v2 of CIFS/SMB are very old and have glaring security holes.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install samba
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils    # This is the one that lets the mount's work
```

I thought I remembered having to do an install with something about cifs... but then I thought I'd heard that Samba was pre-installed now adays

Comment: ...but why did two of the disks mount?  Why didn't all error?